# Subdomain multisite instances having same content

Tags: multisite

I reviewed a site with its subdomains
I saw that the contents of its domains are all the same and created automatically.
And apparently subdomains are made up of three English characters and three numeric characters, with the subdomains of 6 characters.

Below are examples of this subdomain:

- root domain http://example.com/
- http://snu595.example.com/
  *http://jig985.example.com/
- http://xxz318.example.com/
- and etc

Now I ask you:

1. how this automatic blog created in multisite wordpress?
2. how this blogs have same content?
3. how this blogs have Shawn randomly in the footer of content ..

Comment: Please give the correct domains

Comment: @Pat_Morita – Please don't include links to your live site as they may be considered malicious or spam and have no value as soon as your issue got fixed.

Comment: This is propably a combination of a couple of plugins, like multisite domainmapping, content syndicat and so on.